# Query to count values

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables in MySQL:

Persons

```
|ID  | Name    |  Address
---------------------------------
| 1  | Someone |  Somewhere
| 2  | Person2 |  Somewhere else
```

And the table ActivePages

```
|ID  | PersonID |  Page
---------------------------------------
| 1  | 1        |  somepage
| 1  | 1        |  someotherpage
```

Now I need a query to return the following:

```
|PersonID | Count
------------------
|1        | 2
|2        | 0
------------------
```

Who can help me with this? I think its straight forward but I keep getting wrong values...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the `ID` in the ID-PersonID-Count query supposed to refer to?

Comment: That's just an ID, it can be left away... I adjust the example for you ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   SELECT p.ID AS PersonID,
          COUNT(a.PersonID) AS `Count`
     FROM Persons p
LEFT JOIN ActivePages a ON a.PersonID = p.ID
 GROUP BY p.ID
```

Comment: Now I get the same count on both records, so now I have 2 records, but both have the same count value

Comment: @CyberK: it was a little typo, fixed

Comment: One more thing, I have a column 'Active' in my persons table, I only want to count the persons who are active. Where do I need to pass the WHERE a.Active = 'True' part? ;-)

Comment: @CyberK: you said you have `Active` in persons table but after use it as `a.Active`. So where is it? ;-) If it is really `Persons` table - then add `WHERE p.Active = 'True'` (note that alias is `p.`) right before `GROUP BY`

Comment: @zerkms Well there are some more columns in the table, but I didn't want to spend a half an hour making the table look nice to post here ;-) Just added the critical info to clearly express the issue

Answer (score 0):

```
    select personid,count(personid) as count from activepages
     right join Persons on ActivePages.PersonID = Persons.ID group by personid
```

Comment: Wrong. You missed second line with count = 0.

Comment: Wrong again. In this case you will lose almost all persons, that have no any pages (except of random one).